# How to correct the valgrind errors?

Tags: c, gcc, valgrind, glib

I use *valgrind* to check my c program:

```
void mprint(gpointer e, gpointer c);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    printf("%s", "\n(paser-start \n");

    GSList *list = NULL;
    list = g_slist_append(list, "first");
    list = g_slist_append(list, "second");

    int *c = (int *) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    *c = 0;
    g_slist_foreach(list, mprint, c);
    free(c);
    c = NULL;

    g_slist_free(list);

    printf("%s", "\n paser-end)\n");

    return 0;
}

void mprint(gpointer e, gpointer c) {
    int *counter = (int *) c;
    printf("%d: %s\n", *counter, e);
    (*counter)++;
}
```

*valgrind* always outputs: `==20375== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)`. If I comment this line, there is no error: `list = g_slist_append(list, "second");`. But, all examples about `GSList` I've found are shown as that. So, what error did I made? How should I work with `GSList` correctly? The full output of *valgrind*:

```
$ ./debug.sh
rm /home/foo/bar/parser/parser
gcc -std=c99 `pkg-config --cflags --libs glib-2.0` -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -o /home/foo/bar/parser/parser /home/foo/bar/parser/parser.c
==20375== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==20375== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==20375== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==20375== Command: /home/foo/bar/parser/parser
==20375== 

(paser-start 
0: first
1: second

 paser-end)
==20375== 
==20375== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20375==     in use at exit: 4,376 bytes in 12 blocks
==20375==   total heap usage: 13 allocs, 1 frees, 4,380 bytes allocated
==20375== 
==20375== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==20375==    by 0x4EB5085: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4EB57D8: g_private_get (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E93300: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==20375==    by 0x4EB511E: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4EB51DC: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4EB5418: g_mutex_lock (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BAC0: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==20375==    by 0x4EB511E: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4EB53E8: g_mutex_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BBFE: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 4 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C28BED: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==20375==    by 0x4EB511E: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4EB53E8: g_mutex_init (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BC28: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 240 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C270FE: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:694)
==20375==    by 0x4C271A7: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:835)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BDCD: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E937E0: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 252 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C272B8: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:566)
==20375==    by 0x4E7EF88: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BBAB: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C272B8: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:566)
==20375==    by 0x4E7EF88: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BBCB: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 504 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C272B8: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:566)
==20375==    by 0x4E7EF88: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BBEB: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 720 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 9 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C270FE: memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:694)
==20375==    by 0x4C271A7: posix_memalign (vg_replace_malloc.c:835)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BDCD: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E93810: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== 2,032 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 10 of 10
==20375==    at 0x4C272B8: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:566)
==20375==    by 0x4E7EF88: g_malloc0 (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E4BCA8: ??? (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E9348C: g_slice_alloc (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4E94672: g_slist_append (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3200.4)
==20375==    by 0x4008DD: main (in /home/foo/bar/parser/parser)
==20375== 
==20375== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20375==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20375==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20375==      possibly lost: 960 bytes in 4 blocks
==20375==    still reachable: 3,416 bytes in 8 blocks
==20375==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20375== 
==20375== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==20375== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 4)
```

Comment: To who is closing this question: could you please give any excuse for closing it?

Comment: Try setting list to null after calling glist_free. I see reachables in your valgrind output but I don't see the errors it is talking about. The errors happen while the code is running, are you sure this is all the valgrind output?

Comment: @CharlieBurns I tried this after `g_slist_free(list);`: `list = NULL;`. Still 2 errors. Yes, I posted the full *valgrind* output.

Comment: Have you looked for `valgrind` information in the library documentation?  Does the `g_slist_*()` code keep memory allocated behind the scenes (so it is still reachable)?  Is there an API call to release the memory allocated behind the scenes?  Some way of telling the library "all done"? Still reachable is different from, though not necessarily better than, leaking memory.  It might mean there's a global variable with data structures that point to these blocks of memory, and I mean a variable in the library, not in your code.

Comment: Is there a glist tag you could tag this question with? I'm not familiar with the package.

Comment: @CharlieBurns I just added a *glib* tag. Thank you.

Comment: Documentation for [lists](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html) and [slices](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Slices.html) suggest that the library could be hanging onto some space that it allocated on your behalf.  The documentation points to `G_SLICE=always-malloc` observing:
_This will cause all slices allocated through g_slice_alloc() and released by g_slice_free1() to be actually allocated via direct calls to g_malloc() and g_free(). This is most useful for memory checkers_... [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) is a memory checker.

Answer (score 0):

I've set an environment variable: `G_SLICE=always-malloc`. No *valgrind* errors now :-)